# setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener vs setOnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, callback, searchview, listeners

The android SearchView has two methods: setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener and setOnFocusChangeListener. Are they interchangeable? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

1."setOnFocusChangeListener" (inherit from android.view.View) is for the whole view.
2."setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener" is just for the AutoCompleteTextView.

See the code of SearchView:

```
public void setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener listener) {
    mOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener = listener;
}

******

mQueryTextView = (SearchAutoComplete) findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);

******

mQueryTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (mOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener != null) {
                mOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange(SearchView.this, hasFocus);
            }
        }
    });
```